# How does marionette attach rendered views to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js, marionette

I have a very simple setup with Marionette I am trying to get working.

I have a view with a collection:

```
var MyItemsView = Marionette.View.extend({
    template: "#some-template"
});

var view = new MyItemsView({
    collection: new Backbone.Collection([1,2,3,4,5])
});
```

The template is directly imbedded in my HTML

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/html">
        <ul>
            <% _.each(items, function(item){ %>
            <li> <%= item %> </li>
            <% }); %>
        </ul>
</script>
```

I get no output.

When I try to use `view.render()` I also get no output.
When I log `console.log(view.render().el)` I just get an empty `<div>` I don't understand how this can happen? Shouldn't the view be using the template provided?

Another update. This will render with an ItemView or a LayoutView but not a View... wtf is going on here.

This example was taken directly from the Marionette website. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Marionette are you using?  If you are using anything before the 3.0.0 (**currently beta**), you should be extending from an `ItemView` and not a `View` From the Marionette documentation (v2.4.5):

> Note: The Marionette.View class is not intended to be used directly.
>   It exists as a base view for other view classes to be extended from,
>   and to provide a common location for behaviors that are shared across
>   all views.

This behavior changes in v3.0.0 as `ItemView` looks as though it has been removed.

Comment: Based on reading documentation and source this is the correct answer. I was indeed trying to use this class in the wrong way. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it creates a view which is in memory.

You need to tell it where you want this view content to be appended using the [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) option,

or else you should manually append to the DOM like

```
$('body').append(view.el)
```

Comment: Updated my question. This doesn't seem to work for View but does work for Every other type of View...

Comment: @DanielTate is the template script  added after the actual script? can you create a [mcve]?